# Is it natural for clouds to flow near the surface?

Tags: everyday-life, atmospheric-science

A week ago, I have seen something that I have never seen before, Nah it's not a flying dragon, but clouds that were flowing so near my roof (about 5-6 meters above my roof). These are the pictures, I have taken

[image]

Some of the clouds were passing just above the tree. I just want to know if this is a natural scene that occurs very often. What's the reason for clouds to flow so close to the surface?

Comment: The certainly flow just fine higher up. And you can stand on a mountain ridge and have the clouds flow over you just fine. How does a cloud (and the air currents) know how far off the ground they are (besides boundary layer effects)?

Comment: If the pressure decrease with the height, So How come a cloud can come near the surface? Mountains are much higher so that okay.

Comment: Clouds come near the surface all the time. Ever been in a fog bank?

Comment: @JonCuster No, I have never been. What strange is it's not the mountain where I have taken a picture, I also wasn't so cold either. I'm in the midst of the city.

Answer (score 1):

Clouds form when rising pockets of warm air that contain moisture expand and then cool into white, fluffy clumps of water droplets. They usually form higher in the atmosphere because that's where you'd find temperatures low enough for water to condense. We don't just get a uniform fog because the atmosphere is not, and can not come to thermal equilibrium. In its attempts to reach thermal equilibrium, however, we get most atmospheric phenomena that we are familiar with in the present day.

Now, you can actually get clouds at lower heights too, granted that you somehow have pockets of warm air being cooled by something that takes away heat from said pockets - say, a water body, or a large amount of snow. That's how you get to see clouds floating above lakes and near mountain tops (even though they're not nearly as high as the usual cloud formation heights!).

Hope that answers your question satisfactorily!

Answer (score 0):

You can get clouds at different altitudes, and they are named accordingly:

[image: Names of clouds at different altitudes]

Comment: I can see the lowest clouds on your picture at about 1000 meter, What I'm talking of about 40-50 meters above the surface.